# If B is a local noetherian extension of a DVR A such that $\Omega_{B/A}=0$, show that B is a DVR.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $A$ be a discrete valuation ring, $K$ its field of fractions, $L$ a finite extension of $K$.
Let $B$ be a subring of $L$, that is a local noetherian extension of $A$ such that the differential module $\Omega_{B/A}$ is $0$.

Show that $B$ is a DVR.

I know I only need to show that the maximal ideal $m$ of $B$ is principal.
Assuming this is not the case, I could take an element $x\in m\setminus m^2$ and construct a non zero differential from the fact that there is a $y\in m\setminus x B$.

However I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the differential module $\Omega_{B/A}$?

Comment: Maybe this is just rephrasing what you're trying to prove, but if $\Omega_{B/A} = 0$, then $B$ is unramified over $A$. Being unramified implies that $\mathfrak{m}_A B = \mathfrak{m}_B$, where $\mathfrak{m}_A$ and $\mathfrak{m}_B$ are the maximal ideals of $A$ and $B$. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00US